# Mergesort Variation - Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time

Let's say we have a different variation of Mergesort:

```
MergesortVar(A,p,r)
  if p < r then
    q ← (p+r)/2
  Bubblesort(A, p, q)
  MergesortVar(A, q+1, r)
  Merge(A, p, q, r)
```

I want to analyze its time complexity for the best and worst cases.

So in general, we get here:

```
MergesortVar(A,p,r)         T(n)
  if p < r then             O(1)
    q ← (p+r)/2             O(1)
  Bubblesort(A, p, q)       T(n)
  MergesortVar(A, q+1, r)   T(n)
  Merge(A, p, q, r)         O(n)
```

So `T(n)=2T(n)+c•n` is that correct?

How can I then analyze its worst and best cases?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Your `MergesortVar` lacks a base case. It will recur until the stack overflows.

Comment: I miss telling names and illuminating comments in your presentation of `MergesortVar(A, p, r)`.

Comment: Why do you think that `Bubblesort` complexity is `T(n)`?

Comment: @trincot This is the function that we got in class...

Comment: @user58697 You right, it should be `O(n^2)`

Comment: Without base case this question is futile. Tell your teacher they got it wrong on that aspect, and that the running time is infinite (if provided with infinite stack space). You should be the only one getting an A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case is missing in the pseudo code which is a major flaw, and unless you made errors in reproducing it faithfully, this should make you reconsider the quality of the course.

But possibly you got the indentation wrong, because the recursive call should *never* be made unconditionally. Here is a correction:

```
MergesortVar(A,p,r)
    if p < r then
        q ← (p+r)/2
        Bubblesort(A, p, q)
        MergesortVar(A, q+1, r)
        Merge(A, p, q, r)
```

Now to the complexities:

`Bubblesort` has a worst case complexity of O(²), and a best case complexity of O(), provided it does not continue its iterations when there is an iteration that makes no swaps.

`Merge` has a worst case complexity of O(). Depending on its implementation it could have a best case complexity of O(1), because when `A[q] < A[q+1]`, there is nothing to do.

is in this case the size of the given array, which is different for a recursive call.

`BubbleSort` is called on a subarray of size /2, then /4, then /8, ... then 2. So the total time complexity of all `BubbleSort` calls together is:

| Worst Case | Best Case |
| --- | --- |
| O(²(1/4 + 1/4² + 1/4³ + ...)) | O((1/2 + 1/2² + 1/2³ + ...)) |
| = [O(²/3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/4_%2B_1/16_%2B_1/64_%2B_1/256_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) |  |
| = O(²) | = [O()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) |

A similar reasoning goes for the total time complexity of all `Merge` calls together: it is called on a combined array size of , then /2, /4, ...etc, log<sub>₂</sub> times.

So that time complexity is:

| Worst Case | Best Case |
| --- | --- |
| O((1 + 1/2 + 1/2²...) | O(log<sub>₂</sub>) |
| = O(2) |  |
| = O() | =O(log) |

Each recursive call of `MergesortVar` takes constant time if we exclude the time spent on `BubbleSort` and `Merge`, so we get a total time complexity for this overhead of O(log).

So we see that the time complexity of the Bubble Sort component is determining the overall time complexity:

| Worst Case | Best Case |
| --- | --- |
| O(²) + O() + O(log) | O() + O(log) + O(log) |
| = O(²) | = O() |

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your kind reply! I really appreciate it! Can I ask why is `MergesortVar` run in O(log) ? Thanks again!!

Comment: It is O(log)  because of the number of times it is called recursively: it is called first with an array of size , then /2, then /4, ... 2, and the length of this series is log₂ (the number of times you can keep dividing by 2). So really this O(log)  is a measure of the *count* of calls of  `MergesortVar`.

Comment: Alright cool! So I can also write the recurrence relation as `T(n) = T(n/2) + (n/2)^2 + n`?

Comment: Yes, although this would lead to a specific number, while you can only say something about the asymptotic complexity, so this equation would become `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n²/2² + n) = T(n/2) + O(n²)`

Comment: Thanks again! I am not sure that I completely understand why is it `O(n²/2² + n)`, can I write it as `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n²/2²) + O(n)` also?

Comment: Well you wrote `(n/2)^2 + n`, and I wrapped it as `O((n/2)^2 + n)`. This is needed, because what we count is not an exact number -- BubbleSort does not take exactly `(n/2)^2` units of time, nor does `Merge` take exactly `n` units of time, nor can we say what that unit of time is and whether it is the same unit for both. What I am saying is, that these expressions really are about an order of complexity, not an exact number. So the `O` is appropriate here.

Comment: And yes you can write it as `O(n²/2²) + O(n)` also, but the second term is insignificant compared to the first, so it just gets "swallowed" into the first. Also the `1/2²` coefficient is irrelevant for big-O notation, so this all is equivalent to just `O(n²)`.

Comment: Oh I get it now! You right, it is not an exact number so we must use `O` here. Is there any differences between `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n²/2² + n)` and `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n²/2²) + O(n)` ?

Comment: There is no difference between those two.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You really helped me understand everything, I appreciate that! Have a great weekend!